# How to popup Alarm Message without any activity in background?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

In my android i app i can alarm functionality and as well logout functionality. After setting my alarm time i am exiting the app by clicking the logout button.

I am using

```
         ExitActivity.this.finish();  
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(ExitActivity.this,PinActivity.class);  
         intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
         startActivity(intent1);  

         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);  
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
         startActivity(intent);
```

this code to exit the app,which goes to home pin screen and after that it launches the home screen. This is because when i am coming back to my app it launches the pinscreen. Alarm working exactly what i want but while alarm popup message it has the pinactivity in the background(which i don't want). I wan't to get rid out of the pin activity in the background.

This is my receiver class?

```
     public class ShortTimeEntryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     try {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         String message = bundle.getString("alarm_message");

         Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderPopupMessage.class);
         newIntent.putExtra("alarm_message", message);
         newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

How do i do that?
Thanks for your help guys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Alarm Manager to set alarms in Android. The alarm manager holds your alarm and fire an pending intent on alarm time.

First create a pending intent like this :

```
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(CONTEXT, ALARM_ID,  INTENT_TO_LAUNCH, 0);
```

Then use this pending intent to set an Alarm like this :

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ALARM_TIME, pendingIntent);
```

This will start the pending intent at given time.

To remove an alarm you have to recreate the same Pending Intent with same ALARM_ID :

```
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Actually i have done this.. thats what i am doing now but the problem is while Alarm Popup message i am seeing the last used screen on background which i don't need...

Comment: Then why don't you finish your pin activity when alarm popup?

Comment: thats what problem.. is it possible to close the activity from another activity..

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just use the context of the activity which you want to close and call finish() method wherever you want :

`ACTIVITY_CONTEXT.finish()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. Sorry i haven't got any idea about getting the context of Activity.. could you help me out please

Comment: In an easy manner, do something like this :  
**Set a public static variable in your global class like :** 
`public static Context mPinContext;`
**Now in your pin activity on OnCreate method set the mPinContext to pin activities context :**  
`Global.mPinContext = this`;  
**Now when you want to finish the pin activity when alarm popup write something like this :**  
`((Activity)Global.mPinContext).finish();`  
and this will finish you pin activity.  
**Insted of settign a global Context you can also pass Activity context by creating a method**

Comment: thanks.i tried your approach but i am facing java.lang.ClassCastException..    **`public class TimeAndExpensesApplication extends Application{
 
 public static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        TimeAndExpensesApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return TimeAndExpensesApplication.context;
    }
}`**  In PinActivity onCreate   `TimeAndExpensesApplication.context = this;`  **In AlarmPopupActivity onCreate**`((ReminderPopupMessage)TimeAndExpensesApplication.context).finish();`thanks

Comment: **Do it like this**  **// Create a global class**
 `public class Global {
  public static Context context;
 }`
 
**// Set Context**
 `public class YourClass extends Activity {
  
  public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   Global.context = TimeAndExpensesApplication.this;
  }`
  
**//  Get Context just direct use**
  `((Activity)Global.context).finish()`

Comment: Thanks Vipul, What i done is in `((Activity)Global.context).finish` instead of **Activity** i used **CurrentActivity** name.. Now i changed to Activity..I solved the issue and got the expected answer..Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

First create a pending intent like this :

```
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, alarm_id, Pass your data with intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Set an Alarm like this :

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        //19 4.4and above api level
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
 } else {
        //below 19 4.4
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
 }
```

This will start the pending intent at given time.

To remove an alarm you have to Use the same Pending Intent with same `ALARM_ID`:

```
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Now You need to create One Service to catch your Alarm.