# Alarm Popup message not Working properly?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-alarms

I am using alaram in my app.Alarm is working fine with out any problem but while alarm message get populated i am seeing last used activity on back of it. I am expecting only the popup message without any last used activity or any activity in back of it.

Thanks for your help guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. You can see my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720181/how-to-popup-alarm-message-without-any-activity-in-background/10720517#comment14072752_10720517). It may help for some one like me.